# ILOG CPLEX: Constraint assigning a decision variable in specific order

Tags: constraints, linear-programming, cplex, ilog

In CPLEX I built the attached model which I want to use for locating products to locations. The constraint that tries to order the allocation of products to locations in ascending order Stackingorder[s] isn't giving me the desired result.

If a product is allocated in location xi it should have a smaller stackingorder+1 then all products located after location xi.

CPLEX seems to neglect the constraint while all other constraints are met.

How should I change the constraint or the model to get it working?

```
    forall(w in Locations: w+1 in Locations, s in Products) 
 ctStackingorder:
    {(Slot[s][w+1] * Stackingorder[s]) <= Slot[s][w] * (Stackingorder[s]+1);}



int Fixed = ...;
int NbLocations = ...;
range Locations = 0..NbLocations-1;
int NbProducts = ...;
range Products = 0..NbProducts-1;
int Capacity[Locations] = ...;
int LocationCosts[Products][Locations] = ...;
int RequiredLoc[Products] = ...;
int Stackingorder[Products] = ...;

dvar boolean Use[Locations];
dvar boolean Slot[Products][Locations];
dvar int SError[Products][Locations];

minimize
  sum( w in Locations ) 
    Fixed * Use[w] +
  sum( w in Locations , s in Products ) 
LocationCosts[s][w] * Slot[s][w] +
  sum( w in Locations , s in Products )
    SError[s][w] *1000 * RequiredLoc[s];

subject to{

  forall(s in Products )
    ctProductHasEnoughLocations:
      sum( w in Locations)
        Slot[s][w] * Capacity[w] ==  RequiredLoc[s];    

  forall(s in Products, w in Locations: w+1 in Locations)
    ctFacings:
        if(RequiredLoc[s] >1){ Slot[s][w+1]==Slot[s][w];}

  forall( w in Locations, s in Products )
    ctUseSlotProduct:
      Slot[s][w] <= Use[w];

  forall( w in Locations )
    ctMaxUseOfLocation:         
      sum( s in Products ) 
        Slot[s][w] <= Capacity[w];

      forall(w in Locations: w+1 in Locations, s in Products) 
 ctStackingorder:
    {(Slot[s][w+1] * Stackingorder[s]) <= Slot[s][w] * (Stackingorder[s]+1);}
} 

{int} Productsof[w in Locations] = { s | s in Products : Slot[s][w] == 1 };

execute
{
  writeln("Open=",Use);
  writeln("Storesof=",Productsof);
}
```

.dat

```
Fixed = 30;
NbLocations = 6;
NbProducts = 5;
RequiredLoc = [1,1,1,1,1];
Capacity = [1,1,1,1,1,1];
LocationCosts = [ 
   [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ], 
   [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
   [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
   [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
   [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] ];

Stackingorder = [328,326,228,226,226];
```

Comment: Hi, can you also share .dat so that other users could try ? regards

Comment: @AlexFleischer Editted the original post with the .dat content

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not feasible and CPLEX relaxed it. In the relaxation tab you may see:

[image: relaxation]

If you want that constraint to be a hard constraint then you should change it into:

```
forall(s in Products )
    //ctProductHasEnoughLocations:
      sum( w in Locations)
        Slot[s][w] * Capacity[w] ==  RequiredLoc[s];
```

(without label)

And then other constraints will be relaxed.

See:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/usroplexamples/topics/opl_mp_examples_relaxation.html

Comment: Thanks changed the constraints to minimize the error of not meeting a constraint. Which is working fine now. Result Slot[s][w] is feasible and meeting all constraints. But now I try to order the allocation lowest stackingorder to highest. So slot[s][w] * stackingorder[s] >= sum(s in products where x<w)slot[s][x] * stackingorder[s] how can I build this constraint?

Comment: Hi @JLo if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.
If you have a follow-up (different) question, it is suggested to create a new (separate) question rather than using comments. Thanks!